# Sql server docker container is consuming almost all the resources

Tags: sql-server, docker, rancher-desktop

I have Rancher desktop installed in windows machine with WSL enabled. I have created a sql server container. when I attach vscode to running container the. It crashes because the cpu and memory is 100% consume d by vmmem. Any idea what could be the issue?

I tried to upgrade the Rancher desktop with latest version but there is no luck.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Esp. High Disk I/O and high CPU usage within the container. Did you ever find the cause for this?